# SSIS Logging in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a huge number of SSIS 2012 packages from different SSIS projects, often the SSIS packages  names in the different projects are identical.

I use SSIS logging from all the packages to one single table in a log database. I would like to keep it that way, to be sure only to have one database to search for all the SSIS logging.

When I am using the SSIS logging in the packages, is it possible to identify the project name also ? so I can identify what SSIS packages and project that are affected?

BR

Carsten

Comment: I am  thinking can I use the sourceid (DTSID) of the SSIS package from the table sysssislog to find the job jobstep/jobname somewhere in the MSDB ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using package deployment, in which case there is no ssis catalog and no project (per se), hence, no further information about your package.  Logging that writes to sysssislog was designed before the concept of project deployment so that's why that piece of information is missing.  As well, the use of MSDB also predated project deployment so it has no information either.

So there's no simple solution.  I would guess that you could convert to project deployment and take advantage of all of the built in logging and reporting there (which you already said you don't want).  Or you could modify all the packages to log there package id and project name into an additional table.